# Not understanding how Susy calculates widths

Tags: css, susy-compass, susy-sass

I'm not understanding how Susy calculates widths for it's grids. I have a 9 column grid which is nested inside a 12 grid column and the widths aren't calculated as I would expect them to be. Here are my settings:

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    column-width: 60px,
    gutters: 2/5,
    math: static,
    global-box-sizing: border-box
);
```

So my main column has `@include span(last 9 nest);`. So inside that 9 column grid cell if I create another cell using `@include span(1 of 9 inside);` shouldn't the output css be:

```
{
    width: 60px;
    padding: 0 12px;
}
```

Instead what I'm getting is:

```
{
    width: 84px;
    padding: 0 12px;
}
```

What I want is the total column width to be 60 pixels, which is what I expect a single column width to be, and then add padding on the left and right. Is there a way to tell Susy not to add the width to the column width? Also I using padding instead of margin because I need the columns to be flush with each other.

Here's a screenshot of what the grid needs to look like.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If Susy output `width: 60px;` and then added `12px` padding inside (for `24px` gutters), your actual column-width would only be `36px`. In order t give you full `60px` columns and `24px` gutters, The width needs to be set to `84px`.